# convert radio button functionality into checkbox

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a two radio buttons

```
<span class="text_content">Td:</span>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="lastTetanusType" value="Td"
<c:if test="${emergencyContactInfo.lastTetanusType == 'Td' || emergencyContactInfo.lastTetanusType == null}">checked</c:if> >

 <span class="text_content">Tdap:</span>
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="lastTetanusType" value="Tdap"
<c:if test="${emergencyContactInfo.lastTetanusType == 'Tdap'}">checked</c:if> >
```

Now i want to convert these radio buttons into checkboxes with functionality both can be null one null one checked or both checked.
If I checked only a single checkbox then the value `emergencyContactInfo.lastTetanusType=Td`,if i select second one the value of  `emergencyContactInfo.lastTetanusType=Tdap`and finally if i select both then the value of `emergencyContactInfo.lastTetanusType=Td/Tdap`.

Comment: It's great but what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried some jquery function but no success.

Answer (score 2):

what are you trying to say buddy ?
now as i understood that you want to change your radio buttons to checkboxes
not radio buttons to behave like checkboxex
then allright
 change your type to `checkbox`

simpel demo::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put each radio button in separate `radio-groups`. So you can click both at the same time or any one.

Comment: i want checkboxes not radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons can be identified by their class
so as you just need to seperate their classes in your case,
i think "`name`" attribute will do.

Comment: i want checkboxes not radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You have the method `replaceWith()`:

```
$(':radio').each(function(){
    var $newCheckbox = $('<input type="checkbox"/>').attr({name:this.name,value:this.value});
    $(this).replaceWith($newCheckbox );
});
```

Comment: But what about new functionality.